# How to highlight an item of a list in sencha ExtJS ?

Tags: extjs

I want to highlight a particular item after loading the list in sencha. I think we need to do something with the tpl of the  list.So how is it possibe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Ext.list.ListView` or its parent `Ext.DataView`, use `getNode()` to get the HTML element that you want to highlight, then highlight it.

Something like:

```
var node = list.getNode('something');
Ext.fly(node).highlight();
```

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 4.1.1 or newer you can use component method `setHighlightedItem(item)` for that purpose.